# Migrating from Internal API implementation of IPartListener2.partOpened

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I work on a 3.7 RCP app that we are migrating to 4.4 and have decided to use the compatibility layer. We have a class that implements the `IPartListener2` interface and we provide an implementation of the `partOpened` method as coded below:

```java
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    if (partRef instanceof IEditorReference) {
        //force editor area visible
        partRef.getPage().setEditorAreaVisible(true);
        // if the editors are currently minimimized and we try to maximize them, 
             then we'll cause a bug.
        if (partRef.getPage().getPartState(partRef) == 
                                 IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED) {
            return; // so exit here
        }
        //get preferences from local method not included in example
        final boolean maximized = 
            getMaximizedValue(PreferenceConstants.P_BOOL_MAXIMIZED_EDITORS);
        if (maximized) {
            partRef.getPage().setPartState(partRef, IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MAXIMIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

When I debugged a call to this method the instance of `partRef` was of type `org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference`. Also, `partRef.getPage().setPartState(partRef, IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MAXIMIZED)`itself makes a call to an internal workbench method. My question is how do I replace the internal calls/objects referenced with their proper Eclipse 4 equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what the actual class of `partRef` is as long as you only use the `IEditorReference` interface to access it. Values passed to you by Eclipse will often have an implementation class which is internal. As long as you only use the public interfaces these classes implement you are following the rules.

Similarly the `setPartState` call is part of the `IWorkbenchPage` interface. Again the actual class that implements `IWorkbenchPage` will normally be internal.

So there are no issues in this code. It does not matter what Eclipse is using to implement interfaces as long as you stick to using the interface.

As a quick check look at the imports of the source file, if it imports anything with `internal` in the package name there is definitely a problem.